# what approach should i follow to make Timer service in android

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager, android-intentservice

I am  working on an interval timer which make an alarm every interval (E.g. 30mins).
I want to make the timer work in background or when device is in sleep and show a notification,
I was told to use Intent Service but its deprecated. what should i use?
-I want to support until API 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `BroadcastReceiver`. For example, using AlarmManager:

```
int repeatTime = 30;  //Repeat alarm time in seconds
AlarmManager processTimer = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, processTimerReceiver.class);   
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//Repeat alarm every second
processTimer.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
System.currentTimeMillis(),repeatTime*1000, pendingIntent);
```

And create your **processTimerReciever** class:

```
//This is called every second (depends on repeatTime)
public class processTimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Do something every 30 seconds
    }
}
```

Remember to register into **Manifest**:

```
<receiver android:name="processTimer" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="processTimerReceiver" >
       </action>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**EDIT:**

If your app use an internet connection, you can send every 30 mins a notification using Firebase

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can press +1 with the arrow.